# It is possible to pass input files in a config file using terser-js cli?

Tags: uglifyjs

It is possible to pass input files in a config file using terser-js?  Docs only state that the input files should be passed as the first set of arguments.

I ask because I'm getting "The command line is too long" errors.

Comment: I believe it is not possible minify(file, option) and there is no code which sets file = file || option.file so....

https://github.com/terser-js/terser/issues/257